# Issues Parsing XML Data from Zoho CRM API Using SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to parse the following XML data, which is being returned via Zoho CRM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords">
    <result>
        <Accounts>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">941215000005051001</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">941215000003961005</FL>
                <FL val="Account Owner"><![CDATA[Jamie Clark]]></FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Smackers]]></FL>
                <FL val="Phone"><![CDATA[901-308-2556]]></FL>
                <FL val="Account Number"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Industry"><![CDATA[Restaurant]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMCREATORID">941215000003961005</FL>
                <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Jamie Clark]]></FL>
                <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">941215000001076002</FL>
                <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Phillip Geller]]></FL>
                <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-02 10:25:59]]></FL>
                <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-02 17:59:10]]></FL>
                <FL val="Billing Street"><![CDATA[1525 Airways Blvd]]></FL>
                <FL val="Shipping Street"><![CDATA[1525 Airways Blvd]]></FL>
                <FL val="Billing City"><![CDATA[Memphis]]></FL>
                <FL val="Shipping City"><![CDATA[Memphis]]></FL>
                <FL val="Billing State"><![CDATA[TN]]></FL>
                <FL val="Shipping State"><![CDATA[TN]]></FL>
                <FL val="Billing Code"><![CDATA[38114]]></FL>
                <FL val="Shipping Code"><![CDATA[38114]]></FL>
                <FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-02 17:59:10]]></FL>
                <FL val="Stage"><![CDATA[Documentation Pending]]></FL>
                <FL val="Support Contract"><![CDATA[Yes - Free]]></FL>
                <FL val="Service Type"><![CDATA[POS + CC]]></FL>
                <FL val="Active?"><![CDATA[Not Active]]></FL>
                <FL val="Auto Billing"><![CDATA[No]]></FL>
                <FL val="1st Contact Name"><![CDATA[Kevin Jamerson]]></FL>
                <FL val="Virtual HASP key?"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
            </row>
        </Accounts>
    </result>
</response>
```

I am using SimpleXML to parse the XML and I am trying to list out the "Account Name" and "Account Owner" for each row. There are 20 rows in the full XML document. However, instead of getting the individual values for "Account Name" and "Account Owner", I receive the value for the first row...20 times.

Below is my PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);          
$row = $xml->result->Accounts->row;
$value = $xml->result->Accounts->row->FL;
foreach ($row as $rows) {
    foreach ($value as $values) {
        switch((string) $values['val']) {
            case 'Account Name':
                echo $values."</br>";
                break;
            case 'Account Owner':
                echo $values."</br>";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing the `$value` variable's value during the first `foreach` statement.

```
foreach ($row as $rows) {
            $value = $rows->FL;
            foreach ($value as $values) {
                switch((string) $values['val']) {
                    case 'Account Name':
                        echo "Account Name: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                    case 'Case Owner':
                        echo "Case Owner: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                    case 'Status':
                        echo "Status: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                    case 'Subject':
                        echo "Subject: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                    case 'Description':
                        echo "Description: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                    case 'Solution':
                        echo "Solution: ".$values."<br />";
                        break;
                }
            }
```